# WaitForSingleObject( )

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have got myself stuck into a really amazing issue here.The code is like as below.

```
class A
{
   public:  
   A(){  
         m_event =  CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);       // create an event with initial value as non-signalled
         m_thread = _beginthread(StaticThreadEntry, 0, this);    // create a thread 
      }

   static void StaticThreadEntry(A *  obj) {  obj->ThreadEntry();  }

   void ThreadEntry();
};

void A::ThreadEntry()
{
     WaitforSingleObject(m_event,INFINITE);
}


int main()
{
        A a;

        SetEvent(m_event);     // sets the event to signalled state which causes the running thread to terminate 

        WaitForSingleObject(m_thread, INFINITE);  // waits for the thread to terminate

        return 0;
 }
```

Problem :

When the above code is run,sometimes( 1 out of 5 ) it hangs and the control gets stuck in the call to WaitforSingleObject()( inside the main function ).The code always calls SetEvent() function to ensure that the thread would terminate before calling Wait() function.

I do not see any reason why it should ever hang?

Comment: I am sorry people- all answers seem to be wrong. I tried all combination in my code using Sleep() and there is no reason I think why it should ever hang ?

Comment: why isn't it ordered as m_event=Create... then _beginthread?

Comment: I am sorry-my bad. The event is constructed before the thread is created.

Comment: You need to edit the code in the question if it's not correct - many people are pointing out a mistake which you then say in a comment is not there.  At the moment I'm confused so can't help.

Comment: Does this exact test program stick? Is there anything going on at the end of A::ThreadEntry that might wrap one of the endthread functions? Or is there anything that might close the thread handle?

Comment: Why don't you compile your example and see if it reproduces the issue? As I see it, it does not.  There is nothing _wrong_ with this code, except m_event/m_thread scoping, which I assume is just something you missed as part of your example.

Comment: This is not the exact code - but the structure is similar. I can put the exact code if people are interested.

Comment: _beginthreadex() seems to be working - it is not hanging at all-I will try to reproduce it though.But if it does not gets reproduced -that's awesome.

Comment: When asking this type of question it is almost always necessary to post **compilable** code that repros the problem. It's usually hard enough to diagnose timing related bugs - why turn it into a guessing game? If you can't post the real code (because it's too complex, has too many dependencies, or is proprietary), then reducing it down to a small repro case will often have the bonus of showing you the problem, so you won't even need to post a question.

Comment: Thanks a lot people for your inputs...so finally I got this fixed...The problem was in using _beginthread(). I used _beginthreadex() and _endthreadex() and it works fine.It is fixed now and never hangs.I am so delighted. :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is your use of the _beginthread API.  You cannot use the handle returned from this function with the Win32 wait functions.  You should use _beginthreadex or CreateThread.  From MSDN:

> If successful, each of these functions returns a handle to the newly created thread; however, if the newly created thread exits too quickly, _beginthread might not return a valid handle...
>
> You are ... able to use the thread handle returned by _beginthreadex with the synchronization APIs, which you cannot do with _beginthread.

Comment: Are you sure about this fact : You cannot use the handle returned from this function with the Win32 wait functions

Comment: Yeah, I just checked that in the MSDN website.Its strange- I didnt know that.

Comment: beginthreadex() seems to be working - for now it is not hanging at all

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any issues in the code (Assuming event is created before the thread is started in constructor).

- The event is a auto reset event and
  the initial state is non signaled.
- Child thread has to wait until the
  event is signaled.
- Main thread will signal the event and
  waits for child process to terminate.

Assuming this is the complete code (not the sample code ), it looks quite fine to me.

I suggest you to use [process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to observe the state of the event.

**EDIT**:

There is a slight chance that child thread gets terminated before the main thread waits on the thread handle. If the handle is reused for some other kernel objects and main thread will wait infinitely.
Try duplicating the handle using [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251(VS.85).aspx) after thread creation and use this handle in WaitForSingleObject.

Comment: Yes the event is constructed before the thread is created. Yeah,as you stated this code is fine.Answers above are just not making any sense.

Comment: Can you edit the code in question to reflect the order of event creation?

Comment: Handle duplication is quite possible as Windows try to reuse handle values.

Comment: Do not use _beginthread, use _beginthreadex instead. This way you will be responsible for closing the handle. (You need to close the handle then using CloseHandle once you have waited for it)

Comment: If the handle is closed too quickly to call WaitForSingleObject, then it's also closed too quickly to call DuplicateHandle. Apparently, the return value of _beginthread can be obsolete as soon as the function returns. (Why was it ever written that way?)

Comment: @Canopus Are you sure that handles can be re-used?  HWNDs aren't (very likely to be) re-used in NT or better (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/17/3903614.aspx) and I would imagine Windows uses a similar scheme for any handles.  Ditto for WinCE 6 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee482861.aspx.  With a 16-bit counter your odds of getting a handle that used to exist are probably low enough not to worry about.

Comment: Yes it does reuse the handle values. Why not right a small test program to verify it?
        HANDLE hEvent1 = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
 CloseHandle(hEvent1);

 HANDLE hEvent2 = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
 
 if (hEvent1 == hEvent2)
 {
  std::cout << "Handle Values are same";
 }

Answer (score 1):

you might want to consider using [SignalObjectAndWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686293(VS.85).aspx) instead of the seperate `SetEvent()` and `WaitForSingleObject()` calls, as this occurs as a single operation, and would fail immediately if the event could not be signaled.

Comment: Yeah, I could try this.Thanks.

Comment: Note that the "signal" and "wait" are not guaranteed to be performed as an atomic operation. Threads executing on other processors can observe the signaled state of the first object before the thread calling SignalObjectAndWait begins its wait on the second object.

Comment: @TripleS: You're correct. At the time I answered this, the MSDN page described this function as "Atomically signals one object and waits on another object.". I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether the thread handle m_thread is actually valid?

There are circumstances where _beginthread will return an invalid handle - particularly when the thread exits quickly (which certainly could be the case here as the thread could spin up, pass through the wait (as the event is already set) and then terminate).

Use _beginthreadex instead to create the handle, although you would have to call _endthreadex to make sure everything was cleaned up.

Comment: To be clear, in the case Alan Moore is noting, _beginthread()'s return value is a *valid* HANDLE, just no longer a HANDLE for this particular thread, or possibly not even a thread at all. If it happens to be a HANDLE that will never be signaled, (such as a typical file HANDLE) then the wait can never be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The thread will hang if `SetEvent` executes before `WaitforSingleObject` in the thread. So in that case `WaitforSingleObject(m_event,INFINITE)` will wait forever.

Comment: Really? I have the experience that a WFSO entering (with the event it waits for already signalled) it will exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not bad practice to hand out the address of an object prior to that object being fully constructed. We have control of when the new thread will execute `obj->ThreadEntry()`, it may be after the constructor has completed, there is a full object on which to call ThreadEntry, or ThreadEntry may begin prior to the object being constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Hasturkun says that [SignalObjectAndWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686293%28VS.85%29.aspx) is an atomic operation.

However, MSDN disagrees:

> Note that the "signal" and "wait" are
>   not guaranteed to be performed as an
>   atomic operation. Threads executing on
>   other processors can observe the
>   signaled state of the first object
>   before the thread calling
>   SignalObjectAndWait begins its wait on
>   the second object.

Ya, I'm a little confused myself and my head hurts right now, but I'm sure I'll figure it out. It may not be atomic, but it appears to say that it accomplishes making sure that your thread is waiting on the object before the object to be signaled is signaled. Right?